# This inspection warns about local variables before assignment when I use a function to remove certain substrings

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
             State                                         RegionName
0  Alabama[edit]\n                    Auburn (Auburn University)[1]\n
1  Alabama[edit]\n           Florence (University of North Alabama)\n
2  Alabama[edit]\n  Jacksonville (Jacksonville State University)[2]\n
3  Alabama[edit]\n       Livingston (University of West Alabama)[2]\n
4  Alabama[edit]\n         Montevallo (University of Montevallo)[2]\n
```

I am trying to use a function to remove the '(' and '[' but it gives me the following error:

```
This inspection warns about local variables before assignment
```

This is the code and the function that I am using:

```
towns_df = pd.DataFrame(university_towns, columns=['State', 'RegionName'])

# print(towns_df.head())

towns_df = towns_df.applymap(get_citystate(university_towns))


def get_citystate(item):
    if ' (' in item:
        return item[:item.find(' (')]
    elif '[' in item:
        return item[:item.find('[')]
    else:
        return item
```

The error is where I call the get_citystate function. university_towns is the list where it contains (state, city).

## expected output

```py
   State      RegionName
0  Alabama        Auburn
1  Alabama      Florence
2  Alabama  Jacksonville
3  Alabama    Livingston
4  Alabama    Montevallo
```

Comment: You need to define a function before you can call it. `get_citystate` should be defined before the line `towns_df = towns_df.applymap(get_citystate(university_towns))`

Comment: `df[['State', 'RegionName']].apply(lambda col: col.str.replace(r'([\[(].*?[\]\)])\s*\\n?', '').str.strip())`

Comment: @cs95 I understand my code is wonky and the explanation lacking. I am still new to Pandas and coding in python generally. I am using an online tutorial for cleaning data, and this is the code that was provided. I was still trying to understand it myself at the time before this error showed up. Now I simply would like to get this resolved so I can move on to fully learning the rest. Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: OK, great, did you try the code I suggested in my first comment?

Comment: @cs95 No, that didn't work, but I realized my function was written after I called it, which was causing the errors. I just had to move it above.

Comment: Even with that I don't think you'd get the correct answer, but okay

Comment: @cs95 Everything works fine now! I updated the final result into the answer if you'd like to see.

Comment: Sure, by all means feel free to share your knowledge, Q&A style!

Comment: @cs95 Thank you for helping me, have a good day bro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## From [MachineX: Data Cleaning with NumPy and Pandas](https://towardsdatascience.com/machinex-data-cleaning-in-python-ad6fa5ca109e)

- `towns_df = towns_df.applymap(get_citystate(university_towns))` has been incorrectly implemented.

  - `towns_df` is the dataframe with `State` and `RegionName`
  - `.applymap` is updating `towns_df`, using the function `get_citystate`.
  - `university_towns` does not belong in the parenthesis

```
import pandas as pd

# given
data = {'State': ['Alabama[edit]\\n', 'Alabama[edit]\\n', 'Alabama[edit]\\n', 'Alabama[edit]\\n', 'Alabama[edit]\\n'],
        'RegionName': ['Auburn (Auburn University)[1]\\n', 'Florence (University of North Alabama)\\n', 'Jacksonville (Jacksonville State University)[2]\\n', 'Livingston (University of West Alabama)[2]\\n', 'Montevallo (University of Montevallo)[2]\\n']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# display df
             State                                         RegionName
0  Alabama[edit]\n                    Auburn (Auburn University)[1]\n
1  Alabama[edit]\n           Florence (University of North Alabama)\n
2  Alabama[edit]\n  Jacksonville (Jacksonville State University)[2]\n
3  Alabama[edit]\n       Livingston (University of West Alabama)[2]\n
4  Alabama[edit]\n         Montevallo (University of Montevallo)[2]\n

# function
def get_citystate(item):
    if ' (' in item:
        return item[:item.find(' (')]
    elif '[' in item:
        return item[:item.find('[')]
    else:
        return item

# call function
df = df.applymap(get_citystate)

# display updated df
     State    RegionName
0  Alabama        Auburn
1  Alabama      Florence
2  Alabama  Jacksonville
3  Alabama    Livingston
4  Alabama    Montevallo
```

## Additional note:

- The following line of code by [cs95](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4909087/cs95) does the same thing as `def get_citystate`

```py
df = df[['State', 'RegionName']].apply(lambda col: col.str.replace(r'([\[(].*?[\]\)])\s*\\n?', '').str.strip())
```

Answer (score 1):

The function should be created before you call it.

```py
def get_citystate(item):
    if ' (' in item:
        return item[:item.find(' (')]
    elif '[' in item:
        return item[:item.find('[')]
    else:
        return item 

 
towns_df = towns_df.applymap(get_citystate)
print(towns_df.head())
```

And with everything else working, this is the end result:

```
     State    RegionName
0  Alabama        Auburn
1  Alabama      Florence
2  Alabama  Jacksonville
3  Alabama    Livingston
4  Alabama    Montevallo
```

Comment: My code would have worked, you just forgot to assign it back: `df = df[['State', 'RegionName']].apply(lambda col: col.str.replace(r'([\[(].*?[\]\)])\s*\\n?', '').str.strip())`

Comment: Yes, you are right. I made a mistake when I tried your code after moving the function. I tried it again just now to see, and it worked. Thanks.